# how can i do that pattern ?(pattern with asterisks only)

Tags: netbeans

Qu.17 Write down the program to output the pattern given below using appropriate control structures. Use of control structures is compulsory in this program.

(*****)

(****)

(***)

(**)

(*)

(**)

(***)

(****)

(*****)

---

edit: have removed probable extra (**)

Answer (score 2):

sounds like a college assignment to me :)

break down the problem into its simplest form and write a test to check your program.

your first test could be something really simple:

```
can print out single asterisk: (*)
```

then build it up from there:

```
given starting number of 2, prints 3 lines of two asterisks (**), (**), (**)

second line should only have one asterisk (**), (*), (**)

...

given starting number x, prints 2x - 1 lines
```

Comment: @Harish he gave the solution.  He just didn't write the code in a form where you would be able to copy paste it and turn it in as your own work.